# Summarising data frame using maximum counts

Tags: r, plyr

I have this data.frame:

```
counts <- data.frame(year = sort(rep(2000:2009, 12)), month = rep(month.abb,10), count = sample(1:500, 120, replace = T))
```

First 20 rows of data:

```
head(counts, 20)

   year month count
1  2000   Jan    14
2  2000   Feb   182
3  2000   Mar   462
4  2000   Apr   395
5  2000   May   107
6  2000   Jun   127
7  2000   Jul   371
8  2000   Aug   158
9  2000   Sep   147
10 2000   Oct    41
11 2000   Nov   141
12 2000   Dec    27
13 2001   Jan    72
14 2001   Feb     7
15 2001   Mar    40
16 2001   Apr   351
17 2001   May   342
18 2001   Jun    81
19 2001   Jul   442
20 2001   Aug   389
```

Lets say I try to calculate the standard deviation of these data using the usual R code:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(counts, .(month), summarise, s.d. = sd(count))

   month     s.d.
1    Apr 145.3018
2    Aug 140.9949
3    Dec 173.9406
4    Feb 127.5296
5    Jan 148.2661
6    Jul 162.4893
7    Jun 133.4383
8    Mar 125.8425
9    May 168.9517
10   Nov  93.1370
11   Oct 167.9436
12   Sep 166.8740
```

This gives the standard deviation around the mean of each month. How can I get R to output standard deviation around maximum value of each month?

Comment: Please provide the mathematical definition of "standard deviation around maximum value of each month". I have no idea, what that is.

Comment: same as standard deviation around mean, but using maximum values per month instead.

Comment: I reiterate: Provide the mathematical equation or a reference. I'm always keen to learn and I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: edit: so each month has 10 values. I need to calculate the maximum of these 10 values and the average deviation away from this maximum value

Comment: So, you want `mean(max(count)-count)` or `sqrt(sum((max(count)-count)^2)/length(count))` or `sqrt(sum((max(count)-count)^2)/(length(count)-1))`? Just put the formula into the `ddply` call or if you prefer write a function.

Answer (score 1):

you want: "max of values per month and the average from this maximum value" [which is not the same as the standard deviation].

```
counts <- data.frame(year = sort(rep(2000:2009, 12)), month = rep(month.abb,10), count = sample(1:500, 120, replace = T))

library(data.table)
counts=data.table(counts)
counts[,mean(count-max(count)),by=month]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is highly vague. If you want to calculate the standard deviation of the differences to the maximum, you can use this code:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(counts, .(month), summarise, sd = sd(count - max(count)))
   month       sd
1    Apr 182.5071
2    Aug 114.3068
3    Dec 117.1049
4    Feb 184.4638
5    Jan 138.1755
6    Jul 167.0677
7    Jun 100.8841
8    Mar 144.8724
9    May 173.3452
10   Nov 132.0204
11   Oct 127.4645
12   Sep 152.2162
```